# Use directive in ng-bind-html with filter

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have a factory function that returns a directive with value in content attribute

```
.factory('dParser', function (_) {
var parse = function (response) {
return "<val content=response>";
};
return {
        'parse': parse,
       };
    });
```

And a val directive that injects some html

```
.directive('val', [ '$compile, $parse', function ($compile, $parse) {
        return {
          'template': '<span class="value">{{capture1}}</span>',
          'restrict': 'E',
            'link': function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.capture1 = $parse(attrs.content)(scope);
            }
        };
     } ]);
```

And there is the HTML page

```
   <div class=" row" ng-repeat="entry in controller">
  <span class="row" ng-bind-html="entry.values | to_trusted"></span></div>
```

And a service which invokes the factory and returns

```
return {
values = '<span id="rate">' + dParser.parse(set) + '</span>';
};
```

And a filter to_trusted as follows

```
.filter('to_trusted', [ '$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function (text) {
           text = text.toString().replace(/<br\/>/g, '');
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    } ] )
```

The directive `val` however doesn't get resolved? Why does this happen?